# JQuery remove multiple enter when user typing in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery

When users write something, sometimes they leave two or more spaces in a row, is there a way to prevent this with jQuery?

For example:

I don't want to allow user typing like this:

```
Hi Dear,






This is some text.



Second text




Thirt text and .....
```

So we need to delete multiple spaces row like this:

```
Hi Dear,

This is some text.

Second text.

Thirt text and....
```

I think we can do it with jquery keyup function with regex like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("keyup", ".text", function() {
      var text = $(".text");
      text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){2}/g, '$1').replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n){3,}/g, '$1\n');
   });
});
```

Is there a way to do that? I can do this with php regex. But is there a way to do this when the user writes the text without the need for php?

I would like to say that it is possible not to allow extra spaces when writing text.

```
<div class="text" contenteditable="true" placeholder="User can write text here More than three sub-spaces will not be allowed. "></div>
```

Comment: The code snippet that you provided works fine. You probably need to insert the text back to contenteditable after removing multiple enter ... ```$(".text").html(text)```. What is the problem thatt you are facing?

Comment: I have updated the DEMO . Here is the link https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmMbGq.

Answer (score 0):

Do it something like this:

```
var lastKey = '';
$("#id").keypress(function(e){ 
   if(e.which == 13 && lastKey == 13)
      e.preventDefault()
   lastKey = e.which;
});
```

It checks for 2 consecutive enter key presses, and ignores the 2nd one. Its faster and much cleaner than using regex.

Answer (score 0):

using jquery `text` doesn't work on `textarea` the way you would think , use jquery `val` it always work and use event `blur` it fires one time when user is leaving `textarea` you could also use `change` if you want 
here is the working code ,

```
 $('.text').on('blur' , function(){
      $(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/\n\n+/g , "\n") )
 })
```